# Can I suppress background process info?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

When I start a background process, Bash outputs the process ID. Then Bash outputs a status message when the process is complete. Here's what I mean:

```
$ echo foo &
[1] 12345
foo
$ echo bar
bar
[1]+ Done echo foo
```

Is it possible to suppress this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-shell:

```
(sleep 2 &)
```

Comment: :-) Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

You could start it in a separate shell by

```
bash -c 'echo foo &'
```

but you would also have no jobcontrol.

You can also disable job monitoring by

```
set +m
```

then you don't have this message

```
[1]+ Done echo foo
```

but you still get

```
[1] 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable notification by calling

```
set +m
```

before the command.